# If I paste HTML into the cover letter field, will it be preserved?

Tags: support, jobs

I am interested in applying for a job on Careers and wrote a cover letter to include with my application. I would like to include some links in the cover letter, but I'm not sure whether I can simply paste HTML into the field and have it preserved.

After a bit of digging, I found this:

```
tinyMCE.init({
    //...
    valid_elements: "a[href|target=_blank],i,em,strong/b,div[align],p,br",
```

So it appears that the *editor* supports links. Is it safe to assume the HTML will be passed along to the employer unmodified?

The formatting appeared in the preview, so I decided to assume the employer would see it and I submitted the form. The question still stands though.

Comment: To the close voters: this question is about the Stack Overflow Careers product, which is a valid topic for both MSO and MSE. We even explicitly call out Careers in the ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page.

Comment: @Laura I think we should prevent the option to close as "pertains only to a specific site" when [tag:careers] tag is used, or at least show a message saying what you wrote, asking the user to confirm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The HTML you pasted was passed onto the employer, unmodified, since it was part of the accepted tags. What you see in the preview before submitting your application is exactly what the employer sees, so you made the right choice to submit it :)